# Type-hinting for stdClass properties?

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting

Is there a standard way to type-hint the properties that exist on a `stdClass`?

For example, I use some API and get a JSON response. I then parse it with `json_decode`, but I want the IDE to be aware of what properties this `stdClass` object has.

I tried doing it like this:

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonResponse);
/** @var $obj \stdClass */
/** @property String $obj->prop */
```

But PhpStorm still doesn't recognise that `$obj` has the property `prop`.

Is there anyway to get this working?

Comment: `/** @property String $obj->prop */` -- it does not work like that. Your have 2 options: 1) Just use any fields you want, IDE should not warn you about unknown fields as it's a `stdClass` instance. 2) Create some fake class for IDE only and use it instead of `\stdClass` in your typehint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a class that will inherit stdClass and will describe properties. Response object might be converted to it. For example:

```
/**
 * @property string $prop
 */
class SomeClass extends stdClass
{
}

$obj = json_decode($jsonResponse);
$obj = (SomeClass)$obj;
```

Comment: This last line is actually a parse error, you can't cast to a non-primitive type. Just use `/** @var SomeClass $obj */` instead.